There is no polynomial p(x) for which there is a single line that is tangent to the graph of p(x) at exactly 100 points.
False. For p(x) with exactly 100 multiple roots the X-axis is such a line. (This is
essentially the only way: if y = ax + b is such a line for a polynomial q(x), then the X-axis
is such a line for the polynomial q(x) − ax − b, which must have exactly 100 multiple roots.)
This is one of the questions from an entrance exam to an undergraduate degree. I am not able to understand the solution clearly of how the x-axis is a line that can be tangent to a polynomial at exactly 100 points. When I try to imagine a wavy curve comes to mind that has 100 local maxima and goes to positive and negative infinity at the endpoints. It would be very helpful if you could elaborate more on the solution and provide an example or visual element. The motivation behind the answer and the general solution/ result would be very appreciated and a general idea to solve similar questions. The other part of the solution why the x-axis is such a unique line is completely incomprehensible to me. Any help would be most welcome and get me started on a few problems. Thanks

Think about the following product:
$$ f(x) = \prod_{n=1}^{100} (x-n)^2 $$
We can see that this is $0$ at every integer from 1 to 100. Also, because each of these is squared, they will not cross the $x$-axis, but bounce off of it. This means that there will be a tangent line ($y=0$) at each of these minima. Hence, we have that this line is a tangent line at 100 points and because this equation does not equal 0 anywhere else it is a tangent line at exactly 100 points.
It might help to plot this in Desmos if you would like to visualize this, except instead of 100, using a smaller number, like 5.

The gradient is zero at $x=\frac{3}{2}$ but the x-axis is not a tangent at this point since $x=\frac{3}{2}$ is not a zero of the polynomial.

thanks i was stuck for days finding a polynomial
